# Last time a Stored Procedure was executed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

On Sql Server 2000, is there a way to find out the date and time when a stored procedure was last executed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not without logging or tracing, I'm afraid

Answer (score 24):

If a stored procedure is still in the procedure cache, you can find the last time it was executed by querying the sys.dm_exec_query_stats DMV.   In this example, I also  cross apply  to the sys.dm_exec_query_plan DMF in order to qualify the object id:

```
declare @proc_nm sysname

-- select the procedure name here
set @proc_nm = 'usp_test'

select s.last_execution_time
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (s.plan_handle) p
where object_name(p.objectid, db_id('AdventureWorks')) = @proc_nm
```

[[Source]](http://joesack.com/WordPress/?p=101)

Comment: I believe Data Management Views was implemented in SqlServer 2005 and therefore not applicable to sql server 2000.

Comment: ^ Honestly if you're still using SQL 2000 in 2013, finding out the last time a srpoc was run is your last problem